# Keyboard Accelerator with RepeatButton

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, keyboard

There is a [RepeatButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.repeatbutton) which repeats `Click` event in time `Interval` if you are holding the button. And there is pretty nice [KeyboardAccelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-accelerators) support in UWP for supporting keyboard shortcuts. But together it does not work as expected:

```
<RepeatButton Content="Click me"   Interval="500"   Click="RptBtn_Click"  >
    <RepeatButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
       <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="K"  />
    </RepeatButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
</RepeatButton>
```

Now pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> calls `RptBtn_Click` event periodically, **but not with 500 ms interval** as set in `RepeatButton`, but much faster. This is happening because `KeyBoardAccelerator` calls `RptBtn_Click` event repeatedly, but doesn't hold the button for performing `RepeatButton` behavior.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-accelerators) says:

> By design, the accelerator autorepeats (for example, when the user
>   presses Ctrl+Shift and then holds down M, the accelerator is invoked
>   repeatedly until M is released). This behavior cannot be modified.

Ok, I understand why. But I don't know **how to add Keyboard shortcut to RepeatButton**

Answer (score 0):

in this scenario you won't be able to modify the behavior of the interval for the repeat of the app accelerator, only the UI click event itself.
You could manually handle a timer in the event handler to mark the event as handled unless the interval has passed since the last invoke. Alternatively, you could remove the accelerator and handle the keyDown events.

Comment: Hi, I have a related issue, don't want to create a question yet because should be a simple one...I added <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Enter" /> to a button but is not triggered when I'm inside some control like textbox and passwordbox, do you know why? they shouldn't handle any key enter event. thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-accelerators#custom-keyboard-accelerator-behavior), when you use an accelerator the first time, you need to set KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs.Handled=True.  That stops the repeating, as I understand it.  Unfortunately, based on your code, you won't have access to that object because it looks like you're able to call the MenuFlyoutItem.Click event method, which, as I understand it, shouldn't/couldn't be done.  The documentation states that your KeyboardAccelerator tag should include the property "Invoke" which is set to the method you want to call when your key combo is pressed.

Additionally, the call is to a different method with a different signature than the "click" event, so you will either need to call your click event from the accelerator invocation, or you will need to have both your accelerator and your click event call some third method that accomplishes the task you want to do.  I have opted for using a third method to do the work.

Unfortunately for me, I cannot get KeyboardAccelerators to work AT ALL!.